Optimal strategy assuming Geometric Brownian motion?
Let's assume that some stock price follows a geometric Brownian motion with known parameters $\log X_t-\log X_0 \sim (\mu t, \sigma^2 t).$ I'm trying to model the size of the order book (normalized) data given this assumption. For example, let's $B(t,x)$ refer to the size of the total bid orders at rate $x$ and time $t$. I would like to know if we can derive an approximation of the shape of $B(t,x),$ up to some constants?
My general idea is that, if we assume that the market makers are aware of the underlying SDE and its parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$,  then they can behave "optimally" and size their orders according to some optimal criteria. Is this problem well-posed, or is it under-determined?
